# Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have problem with my application. I added uploading image page but i get problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZuIw.png)

Before my project work corretly. I can login in test1 be user and test3. Admin can log test2 and test3, but when i add uploadImage and i wanna log be Admin i get whitelabel, if i change this for user i get this same problem. I think this should be problem with mapping or scaning, my structure maybe is not correctly but idk because i dont have enough experience. Lower i add my code, if someone need more code, ask.

My uploadImage:

```html
package com.example.imageUploader.gui;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.example.imageUploader.ImageUploader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.awt.*;
// problem moze byc z mapowaniem albo zaleznosciami miedzy folderami ze ten jest za wysoko

@Route("uploadImage")
public class UploadGui extends VerticalLayout
{

    private ImageUploader imageUploader;

    @Autowired
    public UploadGui(ImageUploader imageUploader)
    {
        this.imageUploader = imageUploader;

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("upload");
        button.addClickListener(clickEvent -> imageUploader.uploadFile(textField.getValue()));

        add(textField);
        add(button);
    }
}
```

My run:

```html
package com.example.imageUploader;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.imageUploader.gui.UploadGui")
public class ImageUploaderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ImageUploaderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My logging:

```html
package com.example.imageUploader;

import com.example.imageUploader.model.AppUser;
import com.example.imageUploader.repo.AppUserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private AppUserRepo appUserRepo;


    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, AppUserRepo appUserRepo) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.appUserRepo = appUserRepo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test1").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/test2").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/uploadImage").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void get()
    {
        AppUser appUserUser = new AppUser("User", passwordEncoder().encode("haslo123"), "ROLE_USER");
        AppUser appUserAdmin = new AppUser("Admin", passwordEncoder().encode("haslo123"), "ROLE_ADMIN");
        appUserRepo.save(appUserUser);
        appUserRepo.save(appUserAdmin);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageUploader</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>imageUploader</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.1.4</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Screen of my structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYsES.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved. I put this part of my pom.xml in the comment and resolve problem.

```html
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```